# Need some advice on C++ Server for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, c++

I need some help with finding some tutorials on how an iPhone communicate with a C++ based server. I have been searching online for a while and have not found the suitable site. I may have keyed in wrong keywords in the search, so I am asking here if anyone knows how I can learn this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What software / libraries are you using? Protocols?

Comment: You need to understand how client/server works first... ...and then consider how you would write an iPhone client.

Comment: @Josh: Soon, I will have a project that I would need to do that requires me to use data from a server. Which is programmed in C++. The server isn't using any form of webservice. That is all I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are asking the wrong question.

Instead, try to learn how to interface with your C++ server abstractly. This will lead you to a set of steps to do so, such as "open a TPC socket to port XYZ" or "Resolve a CORBA object reference to BlahDiddyBlah".

Then, once you know how to walk, learn how to walk on iPhone.  Googling "iPhone TCP socket tutorial" will be much more productive than Googling something half-under-specified and half-over-specified. (The "under" half being how does the server connect, the "over" half being that it's written in C++)

So step one, figure out how one connects to the server from any sort of program.

Comment: Exactly. You want to figure out what protocol/web service your server is speaking and then figure out how to talk to the web server. It doesn't matter what language the web server is written in.

Comment: Ok, will try your step one :)